# create a typing and deleting effect animation of placeholder in an input box

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create an animated placeholder for an input box which looks like the placeholder is typed and deleted again (like in https://www.squarespace.com/templates ).

I tried for a single string but failed to do so for an array, I have commented the part I tried to change. I am new to Javascript:

```
const words = [
    "Injection",
    "Broken Authentication",
    "Sensitive Data Exposure",
    "XML External Entities (XXE)",
    "Broken Access Control",
    "Security Misconfiguration",
    "Cross-Site Scripting (XSS)",
    "Insecure Deserialization",
    "Using Components with Known Vulnerabilities",
    "Insufficient Logging&Monitoring"
];
let i = 0;
let timer;

function typingEffect() {
    let word = words[i].split("");
    var loopTyping = function () {
        if (word.length > 0) {
            document.getElementById('word').innerHTML += word.shift();
        } else {
            deletingEffect();
            return false;
        };
        timer = setTimeout(loopTyping, 200);
    };
    loopTyping();
};

function deletingEffect() {
    let word = words[i].split("");
    var loopDeleting = function () {
        if (word.length > 0) {
            word.pop();
            // document.getElementById('word').style.font = inherit;
            document.getElementById('word').innerHTML = word.join("");
        } else {
            if (words.length > (i + 1)) {
                i++;
            } else {
                i = 0;
            };
            typingEffect();
            return false;
        };
        timer = setTimeout(loopDeleting, 100);
    };
    loopDeleting();
};

typingEffect();
```

I wanted this to happen in the placeholder of the input tag. Can you help me please?

Comment: Please explain how your current code fails and what have you tried to fix it

Comment: I had commented out what I actually tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.setAttribute()` and `.getAttribute()` to set and append to the placeholder text:

*typingEffect():*

```
let elem = document.getElementById('typer');
elem.setAttribute('placeholder', elem.getAttribute('placeholder') + word.shift());
```

*deletingEffect():*

```
document.getElementById('typer').setAttribute('placeholder', word.join(""));
```

See example below:

```js
const words = ["Injection",
  "Broken Authentication",
  "Sensitive Data Exposure",
  "XML External Entities (XXE)",
  "Broken Access Control",
  "Security Misconfiguration",
  "Cross-Site Scripting (XSS)",
  "Insecure Deserialization",
  "Using Components with Known Vulnerabilities",
  "Insufficient Logging&Monitoring"
];
let i = 0;
let timer;

function typingEffect() {
  let word = words[i].split("");
  var loopTyping = function() {
    if (word.length > 0) {
      let elem = document.getElementById('typer');
      elem.setAttribute('placeholder', elem.getAttribute('placeholder') + word.shift());
    } else {
      deletingEffect();
      return false;
    };
    timer = setTimeout(loopTyping, 200);
  };
  loopTyping();
};

function deletingEffect() {
  let word = words[i].split("");
  var loopDeleting = function() {
    if (word.length > 0) {
      word.pop();
      document.getElementById('typer').setAttribute('placeholder', word.join(""));
    } else {
      if (words.length > (i + 1)) {
        i++;
      } else {
        i = 0;
      };
      typingEffect();
      return false;
    };
    timer = setTimeout(loopDeleting, 100);
  };
  loopDeleting();
};

typingEffect();
```

```css
#typer {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="typer" placeholder=""></div>
```